# Pathfinding from a bitmap

Tags: vb.net, bitmap, path-finding

Is it possible to have a path-finding algorithm go from one end of a bitmap to the other without touching any black lines and only staying on the white pixels?

The bitmap image is formed through a recursive backtracking that then prints it onto the form, but I was wondering if there was a way to have a different bitmap saved at the same time which includes a line showing the solution, which then can be opened in a new form if the user requests it at the end.

The language I am using is Visual Basic and I am using Windows Forms.

Here is an image of the bitmap for an example:

[image]

The goal is to get from the top-left corner to the bottom-right corner without touching any of the lines.

Comment: [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)

Comment: How did you generate the maze?  Did you use a grid?  It appears to be 25 x 25.  If you treat it as such, then you can probably use the A* algorithm.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway It uses cells and its 'digs' its path. The only thing that is saved is the bitmap image. How would I go about adding nodes so that I can do the A* algorithm?

Comment: The [A* algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-star_algorithm) is a generalization of the Dijkstra's algorithm (already linked). Both links provide pseudo code as a general implementation hint. You might also want to take a look at the [Shortest path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem#Linear_programming_formulation). This all depends on how the graph is built; the logic behind it. If you have a simple Bitmap, good luck.